# How to add column alias to subquery in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, alias

I am trying to run a query where I am using subqueries in the select statement.
This works:

```
select   
(select sysdate from dual),   
(select 'municipality' from dual),  
(select count(*) from municipality)  
from dual;
```

But the resulting columnnames are ugly and therefore I want to add the column aliases.

I am trying to run the following query:

```
select   
(select sysdate from dual) as sysdate,   
(select 'municipality' from dual) as tablename,  
(select count(*) from municipality) as count  
from dual;
```

This fails with the ORA 00923: From keyword not found where expected error. 
Somehow, I am missing something.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Your starting code is just an example, right? If that is real, please use `select sysdate, 'municipality' as tableName, count(*) as COUNT from municipality` instead. Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb881/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try wrapping it with double quotes,

```
select
   (select sysdate from dual) as "sysdate",
   (select 'municipality' from dual) as "tablename",
   (select count(*) from municipality) as "count"
from dual;
```

`SysDate` is a reserved keyword. Although, `COUNT` is an aggregate function but it is permitted to be used.

- [Oracle Reserved Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)

Comment: Life can be so simple. Off course I have to use quotes. Thanks for your really quick answer

Answer (score 1):

The only error you had in your code was using keywords sysdate and count as aliases, which is no-no... Using AS is optional also. This works as intended:

```
select   
 (select sysdate from dual)  s_date,            -- NOT sysdate
 (select 'municipality' from dual)  tablename,  
 (select count(*) from dual) as cnt             -- NOT count
 from dual;
```

It is OK to use count but in real world it is not advisable and pro-s would not use keywords.